# How can we display dynamic modal popup in codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a Codeigniter project which displays database information in the form of cards, having an option for Read More. I want to display the modal popup with the selected row content. For now the code I'm working is displaying only the first row, and if model target is removed the code is displaying correct contents but its not showing in form of modal. Please assist with the query.

Code for view starts here

```
<div class="row clearfix">

<?php 
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM services_offered LIMIT 15");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        echo "<div class='col-lg-4 bottommargin-sm'>";
        echo "<div class='feature-box media-box fbox-bg'>";
        echo "<div class='fbox-media'>";
        echo "<a href='#'><img src='$row->swo_images' alt='Featured Box Image' style='height:250px; width:450px;'></a></div>";
        echo "<div class='fbox-content fbox-content-lg'>";
        $string = $row->swo_brief_intro;
        $string = word_limiter($string, 15);
        echo "<h3 class='nott ls0 font-weight-semibold'>$row->swo_image_heading<span class='subtitle font-secondary font-weight-light ls0'>$string</span></h3>";
        echo "<a href='Fetch/getDetails/{$row->id}' class='button-link border-0 color btn-edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#whatwedo'>Read More</a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";


        // section for modal starts here
        echo "<div class='modal fade' id='whatwedo' tabindex='-1' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-dialog'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-header'>";
        echo "<h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel'>$row->swo_image_heading</h5>";
        echo "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>";
        echo "<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>";
        echo "</button>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='modal-body'>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='modal-footer'>";
        echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>";
        echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Save changes</button>";
        echo " </div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

        // section for modal starts here

        
    }
?>
```

Code for the Controller starts here

```
public function getDetails($id)
    {


        $row = $this-> db
                -> select('swo_brief_intro, swo_image_heading, swo_images')
                -> where('id', $id)
                -> limit(1)
                -> get('services_offered')
                -> row();
        
        if (isset($row))
        {

        echo "<div class='modal fade' id='exampleModal' tabindex='-1' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-dialog'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-header'>";
        echo "<h2 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel'>$row->swo_image_heading</h2>";
        echo "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>";
        echo "<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>";
        echo "</button>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='modal-body'>";
        echo "<label>$row->swo_brief_intro</label>";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<img src='".base_url().$row->swo_images."' class='img-fluid' alt='' style='height:250px; width:650px;'>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<div class='modal-footer'>";
        echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>";
        echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Save changes</button>";
        echo " </div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        }
            
    }
```

Please assist for the query. Thankyou

The view would be like this

but the modal is always displaying the first content

[image]

[image]

Comment: please show image format what you want?

Comment: @KUMAR. I have added the image. After the user is clicking on Read More, a pop up should appear with the same content that is selected. but it is always showing the first row entry.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the modal different ID each modal or services, ID must unique for each services.

give id for the button

```
echo "<a href='fetchDetails' class='button-link border-0 color btn-edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#idmodal'>Read More</a>";
```

and give the modal also the same id

```
echo "<div class='modal fade' id='idmodal' tabindex='-1' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
```

you can use services id in your database or give it a unique name make sure the button and the modal have the same id.

btw I already answered this on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062055/how-to-fetch-row-details-in-popup-modal-using-codeigniter/66202432#66202432)