# Can we display data on click in modal popup? Please assist how it can be done using CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, modal-dialog, popup

I am developing a blog using Codeigniter where the details are being displayed in a bootstrap card with the "Read More" feature. The code is fetching data dynamically and is displaying all the details in the card, but once clicking on 'Read More' it is only displaying the first row data. What can be done to fetch the particular row data in modal popup against which the Read More button is clicked?
Here is the code for fetching the data and displaying in card:

```
<div class="row clearfix">

<?php 
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM services_offered LIMIT 15");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        echo "<div class='col-lg-4 bottommargin-sm'>";
        echo "<div class='feature-box media-box fbox-bg'>";
        echo "<div class='fbox-media'>";
        echo "<a href='#'><img src='$row->swo_images' alt='Featured Box Image' style='height:250px; width:450px;'></a></div>";
        echo "<div class='fbox-content fbox-content-lg'>";
        $string = $row->swo_brief_intro;
        $string = word_limiter($string, 15);
        echo "<h3 class='nott ls0 font-weight-semibold'>$row->swo_image_heading<span class='subtitle font-secondary font-weight-light ls0'>$string</span></h3>";
        echo "<a href='#' class='button-link border-0 color btn-edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#whatwedo'>Read More</a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        // section for modal starts here
        echo "<div class='modal fade' id='whatwedo' tabindex='-1' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-dialog'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
        echo "<div class='modal-header'>";
        echo "<h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel'>$row->swo_image_heading</h5>";
        echo "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>";
        echo "<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>";
        echo "</button>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='modal-body'>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='modal-footer'>";
        echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>";
        echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Save changes</button>";
        echo " </div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

        // section for modal starts here
    }
?>
```

What else it could be possible with? Please assist. Thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display dynamic modal popup in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66152354/how-to-display-dynamic-modal-popup-in-codeigniter)

Comment: this modal is fetching only the first detail from the data.

Comment: means what ......??

Comment: when clicking on the read more button, every model that pops up shows the very first row of the database. Even if the row with fifth ID is pressed the modal will display only the first  row data

Answer (score 0):

you should give different ID for each set of button and the modal

for the button

```
echo "<a href='#' class='button-link border-0 color btn-edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal".$row->id."'>Read More</a>";
```

for the modal

```
echo "<div class='modal fade' id='modal".$row->id."' tabindex='-1' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
```

so 1 read more button will associate with 1 modal

if you have ID in your table you can do something like this

```
foreach($data as $dt){
echo "<a href='#' class='button-link border-0 color btn-edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal".$dt->id."'>Read More</a>";

echo "<div class='modal fade' id='modal".$dt->id."' tabindex='-1' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
}
```

if you dont have ID you can do this

```
$counter = 1;
foreach($data as $dt){
    echo ("<a href='#' class='button-link border-0 color btn-edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal".$counter"'>Read More</a>");
    
    echo ("<div class='modal fade' id='modal".$counter"' tabindex='-1' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>");
counter++;
    }
```

you will achieve the same result.

Comment: The data is being fetched dynamically so only one button is mentioned inside foreach loop, by which it is not possible to assign individual id for each card entry.

Comment: its possible, if you have id in your table you could use that id and use it in modal link id and the modal itself, if you dont have id in your table, just assign it with number that Incremented, Ill edit my answer @VIVEKROBINKUJUR

Comment: Will try with id. Thankyou